Android: Deleting files in Documents turn to be hidden instead
Android Version 13.
I store my Debug files in the internal Public Documents directory (Documents/Appname/Debug/).
When I manually deleted these files with a File Manager, my App got Access Denied errors on the non-existing files when trying to override/add to it.
Then I deleted the entire directory tree, and re-started the App which re-created the directory tree. This actually worked.
But I still got the access denied errors while trying to write to the original Debug filename. I could save files with other names okay.
Only after a full reboot of the device, this finally cleared.
Is there a known issue that (manually) deleting files only causes them to become invisible?

When manually deleting files on newer Android phones they are not immediately deleted but moved to trash. Well unlike on Windows where deleted files are actually moved into trash folder based on description of your problems I'm guessing on android files only get marked as being deleted. Deleted files on Android should be permanently deleted after 30 days. Have you tried deleting of this files programmatically? When deleting files programmatically as far as I know they always get deleted permanently right away.
